# Hyperbolic sin derivation

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zd3RyRk6wYI

On Khan Academy, Sal derives the hyperbolic function of sin in terms of $i\theta$. My question is, how did he get rid of the $i$ in the denominator? I know he substitutes $x$ in for $i\theta$, but I still don't understand how he got rid of the $i$ in the denominator.

I tried justifying his math but I just don't understand how that imaginary number is removed. Could someone justify his math? Thank you.

Comment: He never derives the hyperbolic functions.  He $defined$ them, and said he would explore them later.

Answer (score 1):

He is just defining the functions that way. He is **not** deriving them from the normal $\sin$ and $\cos $ functions, although granted it looks a little confusing with the arrows. The arrows are just to indicate that he defines $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ analogously to $\sin$ and $\cos$ respectively.